# How many leads we use for parallel trends testing in daily data (difference-in-differences)?

Tags: econometrics, difference-in-difference

In a difference-in-differences setting, if we deal with yearly data, we normally test the parallel trends assumption for 3 or 4 years before the event dates. However, when dealing with daily data, **how many days before the event do we need to use for parallel trends testing**? Is there any reference for it?

In my case, $N = 126$ and $T = 500$.

Comment: Did my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/542194/how-many-leads-do-we-include-for-parallel-trends-testing-in-daily-data-differen) address all of your concerns?

Comment: Thanks @ThomasBilach , it answered my question.